# how to write 'If response body is JSON()-able'

Tags: json, python-2.7, dictionary, python-requests

So I've been looking at this for a while and can't think of a way to do it.

I need a way to know if the response body can be converted to a dictionary without triggering a trace back.

```
import requests
import json

session = requests.Session()

url = "www.something.com"
response = session.get(url=url)

if response.json():
    # et cetera
```

I may receive a plain/text response body that just says "OK" or some other string, and need a way to identify the difference.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just check the response's content-type header ?

Comment: Thats a good way too. You mean like so?

if "application/json" in response.header:

Comment: `response.headers["Content-Type"].startswith("application/json")̀` should be ok. Of course this will only work with properly implemented APIs - quite a few apps can return complete garbage (incorrect content-types, crappy WP plugins inconditionnally adding HTML content at the end of __all__ responses, etc), so unless you know for sure the API you're requesting is clean, you'll still want to use a try/except block. And you of course want to first check the response status code ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a perfect use case for a try/except block:

The try/except allows you to "try" something, and if it throws an exception, of the type specified after the except command, it will not stop your program but silently continue with the content of the except block.

see : https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

```
import requests
import json

session = requests.Session()

url = "http://www.something.com"
response = session.get(url=url)

try:
    content = response.json()
except ValueError:
    # do whatever you want in case response can't be JSON()-able
    content = response.text

print(content)
```

Comment: But wouldn't this throw an exception if the response is text?

Comment: @Meeky333 no, it will just return the content of the response as a text and not as a json, now it was just to show you a way to return the response whether it's a json or plain text, but you can do whatever you want after the except: ValueError